# Build a comma seperated list of a SharePoint People/Group field which allow multiple selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

We have the following:-

1. SharePoint list which have a field of type People/Group which allow multiple selection
2. Planner

Now we want to loop through all the SharePoint items >> and for each item >> to create a Planner task >> assign the Planner task to the users defined inside the People/Group field... but I am not sure how I can implement the scenario of building a comma separated list of a SharePoint People/Group field which allow multiple selection, so i
I can define this comma separated list inside the Assigned User Ids's planner field:-

[image]

In other words,  I want to build a separate comma separated list for each item.. so the loop through the GetItems should build the comma separated list for all the users inside the item's People/Group field >> then create a planner task.. so at the end we will have a planner task for each SharePoint item, and both the item and the planner task will have the same assigned to users.. I hope this explain my case.. any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is to create a string variable and then create an "Apply to each" action that appends the MultiPerson field Email value and a semicolon to the variable.

Key points from my example flow:

1. Get all items
2. Initialise a string variable `varPeople`
3. `Get Item` from the `Get Items` action (creates an apply to each)
4. Append to string variable `varPeople`: `MultiPerson Email;` (creates another apply to each)
5. Use varPeople in your "Create a task" action

[image]